# postfix SMTP 550 5.7.60 SMTP

Tags: postfix-mta, rt

I'm running request tracker 5 on Ubuntu 20.04 with postfix but I can't send email from RT.
When I send test email it works.
This is my `main.cf` file

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

smtp_sasl_type = cyrus

smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login

smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes

sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay

smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem

smtp_use_tls = yes

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
relayhost = mail.example.com:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

and my log `/var/log/mail.log`

```
Nov 16 00:11:46 rt5new postfix/smtp[11975]: warning: mail.example.com[x.x.x.x]:587 offered no supported AUTH mechanisms: 'GSSAPI NTLM'
Nov 16 00:11:46 rt5new postfix/smtp[11975]: 53793301166: to=<www-data@fcc.am>, relay=mail.example.com[x.x.x.x]:587, delay=31, delays=0/0/31/0.02, dsn=5.7.60, status=bounced (host mail.example.com[x.x.x.x]:587 said: 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Comment: The error code shows that the realy supports GSSAPI and NTLM authentication methods. Unfortunatelly I don't have such a server to try with but this seems promissing:

https://punctuatednoise.wordpress.com/2017/03/22/network-administration-kerberized-postfix/

Comment: Thanks for replay. But when I send email  with this command 
echo "Hello World" | mail -s "Test Message" myemail@gmail.com -aFrom:alert@example.com

Comment: The email statues=sent  and I resave email, but in logs shows same warring